# Is casadi suitable for data fitting?

Tags: optimization, automatic-differentiation

Quite often I do fit some ODE or DAE systems to my data (small to medium sized problems). Via the assimulo package, I found Casadi and read a bit about the language modellica.

Casadi offers automatic differentiation and an interface to ipopt. As far as I understood. It is designed to solve and optimize ODE or DAE systems but until now I havent found a report of someone using it for datafitting.

Would it be reasonable to use casadi (or jmodellica) for such a task ? The combination of Ipopt with Casadi seems to be very powerfull.